# Using greedy algorithm within two lists in Python

Tags: python, list, greedy

We observe a particular data sample explained by an int value `n` and two lists `A` and `B`, where the two lists contain integer element or elements ranging from `1` to `n`, and the elements in each list aren't repeated. (There could be the same element in both lists, however.)

- `n` represents the size of the observed sample.
- Elements in `A` represent the numbers that are 'taken out' from the sample. Hence, if `n=5` and `A=[2,3]`, the size of our resulting sample would be `3`.
- Elements in `B` represent the numbers that are 'put back into' the sample. The maximum size of the resulting sample cannot exceed `n`.
- However, the elements in `B` can only be put back in if and only if there is an element in `A` that is either equal to the element in `B`, or one less or greater than the element in `B`. For example, if `n=5, A=[2,3], B=[4]`, the size of our sample would be `4`, as there exists an element in `A` that is one less than the element in `B`.
- Finally, the elements in `B` are only considered once if they are 'put back in'. If `n=5, A=[2,3,5], B=[3,4]`, even though the elements in `B` satisfy the condition twice each, the size of the resulting sample would still be `4`.

Some of the test cases are given:

```
n   A       B           return
5   [2, 4]  [1, 3, 5]   5
5   [2, 4]  [3]         4
3   [3]     [1]         2
```

I'm aware that this is a type of a greedy algorithm (which I am not super familiar with), but I also tried the following:

```
def solution(n, A, B):
    count = n - len(A)
    for i in range(len(B)):
        if B[i]-1 in A:
            count += 1
        elif B[i]+1 in A:
            count += 1
        elif B[i] in A:
            count += 1
        else:
            count += 0
    if n > count:
        answer = count
    else:
        answer = n
    return answer
```

While this seemingly works, it doesn't take into account that the elements in `B` cannot be considered once they are put back in already. Is there any edit I can make to my code, and how would this problem be optimally solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the key was to use `set()`in order to retrieve the set without any overlapping elements first, and then start removing the elements that are gone over (which is done similarly to my initial code).

```
def solution(n, A, B):
  B_uniq = set(B)-set(A)
  A_uniq = set(A)-set(B)
  for i in B_uniq:
    if i-1 in A_uniq:
      A_uniq.remove(i-1)
    elif i+1 in A_uniq:
      A_uniq.remove(i+1)
  return n-len(A_uniq)
```